# Spring boot's convertAndSendToUser not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, web

I'm new to Spring boot and trying to learn it. I'm following a [tutorial](https://www.dariawan.com/tutorials/spring/build-chat-application-using-spring-boot-and-websocket/) on how to make a simple one-to-one chat app.

Everything is working fine except that messages aren't getting sent between users. Messages get from the sender to the server but when `convertAndSentToUser()` nothing gets to the other client (recipient).

Here's the message broker configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketMessageBrokerConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/user");
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/queue");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        config.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/broadcast");
        registry.addEndpoint("/broadcast").withSockJS().setHeartbeatTime(60_000);
        registry.addEndpoint("/chat").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
        registration.interceptors(new UserInterceptor());
    }
}
```

And the controller that handles new connections:

```java
@RestController
@Log4j2
public class WebSocketConnectionRestController {
    
    @Autowired
    private ActiveUserManager activeSessionManager;
    
    ...

    @PostMapping("/rest/user-connect")
    public String userConnect(HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute("username") String userName) {
        String remoteAddr = "";
        if (request != null) {
            remoteAddr = request.getHeader("Remote_Addr");
            if (remoteAddr == null || remoteAddr.isEmpty()) {
                remoteAddr = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");
                if (remoteAddr == null || "".equals(remoteAddr)) {
                    remoteAddr = request.getRemoteAddr();
                }
            }
        }

        log.info("registered " + userName + " " + remoteAddr);
        activeSessionManager.add(userName, remoteAddr);
        return remoteAddr;
    }


   ...

}
```

Finally, here's the controller that handles new messages:

```java
@Controller
@Log4j2
public class WebSocketChatController implements ActiveUserChangeListener {
    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate webSocket;

    ...
    
    @MessageMapping("/chat")
    public void send(@Payload ChatMessage chatMessage) throws Exception {
        ChatMessage message = new ChatMessage(chatMessage.getFrom(), chatMessage.getText(), chatMessage.getRecipient());
        log.info("sent message to " + chatMessage.getRecipient());
        webSocket.convertAndSendToUser(chatMessage.getRecipient(), "/queue/messages", message);
    }

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the problem. The tutorial had a `UserInterceptor` which links the session id for new connections to the username but it was trying to cast an Arraylist to a LinkedList so I just casted it to a List instead:

```java
public class UserInterceptor implements ChannelInterceptor {
    
    @Override
    public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
        StompHeaderAccessor accessor
                = MessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message, StompHeaderAccessor.class);

        if (StompCommand.CONNECT.equals(accessor.getCommand())) {

            Object raw = message
                    .getHeaders()
                    .get(SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.NATIVE_HEADERS);

            if (raw instanceof Map) {
                Object name = ((Map) raw).get("username");
                if (name instanceof List) {
                    accessor.setUser(new User(((List) name).get(0).toString()));
                }
            }
        }

        return message;
    }
}
```